# Tastypie 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_clone' error

Tags: django, json, tastypie

I am using tastypie (v0.11) and django(v1.6.1) on windows operating system using pycharm IDE. I am using virtual environment within pycharm. The django model and related ORM cruds work fine and I am using postgresql with psycopg2 driver. Now, I am trying to create a simple REST based request-response framework utilizing json payloads. While trying to test the REST request-response, I keep getting a strange error in the response. The error is as follows:

```
**AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_clone' error.**
```

The url used for testing is

```
http://localhost:8000/api/comment?format=json
```

***And YES ... the Comment table in the database does have records.***

I have already spent a day trying to figure what's wrong. I tried using two other versions of tastypie (v0.10 and v0.9), but the error remains. Any help and guidance will very much be appreciated. Many thanks !!

My code is as follows:

**The django model class**

```
from django.db import models

class Comment(models.Model):
    ID=models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    text=models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**The tastypie resource class**

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from pie.models import Comment

class CommentResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset=Comment.objects.all()
        resource_name="comment"
```

**The urls.py file**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from pie.api import CommentResource
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

res=CommentResource()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^api/', include(res.urls)),
)
```

Comment: Going into second day trying to resolve this. I tried the same thing with Eclipse / PyDev IDE. The same problem arises. Leads me to believe that it is something to do with django-tastypie or postgres.

Comment: Phewww  .. finally resolved it. The test servers within Eclipse and PyCharm were not refreshing the server configurations and the django code was not getting deployed. The browser was also not being helpful as it was caching and displaying old responses. A simple restart of my laptop did the trick - the cache got cleared and new configurations took effect and the api works like a charm. (Just FYI - I had restarted my IDES and Browsers multiple times to resolve this, but it did not work). My machine had to be restarted for things to start working.